# Laplacian in polar coordinates for constant r

Tags: calculus, physics, polar-coordinates, laplacian

So, this is a problem actually motivated by a physics problem that I was facing but is again a math question. So, in polar coordinates, we can write $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and using that we can derive the expression for the laplacian-
$$\nabla^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$$

But now, if I have a problem where suppose the body rotates in a circle of some constant radius R, then without any logical explanation, many authors write that the Laplacian transforms as follows-
$$\nabla^2=\frac{1}{R^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}$$
For some reason, the derivatives with respect to r vanish and become 0. I understand that probably if I try to derive the Laplacian with $x=R\cos(\theta)$ and $y=R\sin(\theta)$ where $R$ is a constant, I would get the above expression. But suppose, I know the expression for the Laplacian in polar coordinates, is there any way to transform this so that I directly get the result for the transformed expression when $r$ is constant (which ultimately begs for the explanation of the expression above)? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $\frac{\partial }{\partial r}=0$. This is true for any operator - if you restrict their domain to their kernel, they become the $0$ operator.

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain it in a simpler way. I'm not very familiar with the term "restricting the domain" and "kernel". I'm familiar with multivariable calculus and stuff.

Comment: If a function doesn't depend on r, then it's derivative with respect to r should be 0.

Comment: As in? Sorry. I don't understand. Because we didn't talk about any function here.

Comment: Actually, I thought so too. That this would mean that the function I'm talking about is independent of r. But doing that with proper notation caused some difficulty.-
(1) If I derive the $\nabla^2$ with r kept constant, it would give the expression that I was looking for.
(2) If I assume that $\nabla^2$ acts on some function independent of r, what would you do with $1/r^2$ term? If the radius were $a$, then how do you do it rigorously?

Comment: Okay. Sure, if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that argument is not rigorous. But anyway, consider the functions $f(x) = \sin x$ for different domains. If we set the domain to $\Bbb{R}$, then this is the regular $\sin x$ we know. But if we instead set it to $\pi\Bbb{Z}$, what would distinguish this function from $f(x) = 0$ on the same domain? Nothing, is the answer, so we say that those two functions are equivalent. An operator (like $\nabla^2$ ) is a "function" that eats our usual functions and spits out other functions. The problem restricts the domain of $\nabla^2$ to functions with no $r$ dependence.

Comment: The word "kernel" refers to the subset of things in the domain that make a function vanish. $\pi\Bbb{Z}$ is the kernel of $\sin x$ and the set of functions without $r$ dependences is the kernel of the $\frac{\partial }{\partial r}$ operator. If you set the domain of a function to only the set of things that vanish under it (i.e. restrict the domain to the kernel), then the function is identical to the zero function.

Comment: Okay. So, let's say I have the function $f(\theta)$. Now-$$\nabla^2f(\theta)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f(\theta)}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 f(\theta)}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}$$
So, the first two terms vanish and now I have $$\nabla^2f(\theta)=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}$$
Now how do I incorporate the fact that $r=a$?

Comment: ...just plug it in?

Comment: Eh. I mean, then if I did that then the derivatives initially would look weird $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$.Derivatives w.r.t. a constant. I'm sorry. I'm getting confused.

Comment: What you're trying to do is a syntax error. The $r$ in the derivative is not a variable you can plug numbers into. For example with normal single variable calculus was $\frac{d}{d 3}$ a sensical expression?

Comment: Nope. That's why I am so confused. "When" do I plug in the fact that $r=a$?

Comment: At the very beginning just like you did, that's what you needed to understand from the domain discussion. So it should have read $$\nabla^2 f(\theta) = \frac{1}{a} \frac{\partial f(\theta)}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2 f(\theta)}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{a^2} \frac{\partial^2 f(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}$$ before simplifying.

Comment: Looks like I'll have to revise calculus again. I got it. Thanks a lot.